Prevent recursion in Apache Commons FileAlterationObserver
I'm hoping to use Apache Commons directory monitoring, but in my first attempts I've discovered that it's checking recursively through subdirectories. That's way more than I want (and presumably lots more overhead, too).
FileAlterationObserver observer = new FileAlterationObserver(new File(directoryPath));

Is there a way to switch off this behavior so that I only get notified of changes within the specified directory?

If you read the javadoc FileAlterationObserver there is an overload which accepts FileFilter. Pass in a filter that checks any file has same parent as the selected directory:
File dir = new File(directoryPath);
FileAlterationObserver observer = new FileAlterationObserver(dir, f -> dir.equals(f.getParentFile()));

I don't use this class so there may well be a better way, or use WatchService.

Tnx DuncG. I tried the filter and it seems to work. That said, won't this still incur all the overhead of recursion? (FYI I tried WatchService but it seemed too slow for my purposes.)

As above, I don't use FileAlterationObserver so can't comment. I do use WatchService and it is very effective and can scan one folder only. WatchService is IMO a poorly specified API, most issues I see on SO are because code samples respond to every event it publishes and so do many times the amount of work needed to catch-up - mostly likely this was your problem too. For example
